# Comparing string-like types in template function

Tags: c++, string, templates

I want to write a functor, that compares a string-like type to another. One side of the comparison is set once at initialization and reused.

The types I want to support in any case are `std::basic_string`, `std::basic_string_view` and `char*`, but other like `std::byte*` as well as `std::array` and `std::vector` are interesting, too.

My first implementation looks like this:

```
template<typename StringType>
class StrcmpAlgorithm {

    StringType pattern;

  public:
    StrcmpAlgorithm(const StringType& p) : pattern(p) {}

    template<typename InputString>
    bool operator()(const InputString& input)
    {
        return input == pattern;
    }
};
```

However, this solution is quite limited, as the usage of the equals operator limits the types I can use and might even do the wrong thing (for example when comparing with a C string).

I'm not really sure how I should approach this. Provide multiple overloads for the call operator? Use constexpr-if and check for the type?

Essentially, having the lhs of the comparison a template parameter (`StringType`) and the rhs a different template parameter (`InputString`) leads to a combinatorical problem, even if the STL already provides some of all possible comparions. Eliminating one of those would make the whole thing much easier. But for the `pattern` member, I need at least the possibility to store strings with different character widths, as well as having the choice between a value and a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **generally** best approach is template specialization, meaning that the template class will behave differently on char*, std::array, etc.

Note, that if you have `std::basic_string_view`, then you can convert all of the types you mentioned to a string view, and thus use the built-in comparison function. So in your case I would implement it a bit different:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::string_view toStringView(const T& object)
{
    // covers containers (std::string_view, std::array, std::vector, std::string)
    return std::string_view(object.data(), object.size());
}

template<typename T>
std::string_view toStringView(const T* ptr)
{
    // Pointer, in this case you would need a null-terminator string.
    return std::string_view(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ptr));
}

template<typename StringType>
class StrcmpAlgorithm {

    StringType pattern;

  public:
    StrcmpAlgorithm(StringType p) : pattern(std::move(p)) {}

    template<typename InputString>
    bool operator()(const InputString& input)
    {
        return toStringView(input) == toStringView(pattern);
    }
};
```

Of course, this example can and should be improved to support `std::wstring_view` and to fail on incompatible types (such as `char**`).

Comment: I'd like to avoid conversions where they are not neccessary. I can compare `std::string` and `std::string_view` just fine. Also, in your example, having `StringType` be anything else than `std::string_view` is simply a waste.

Comment: You can always avoid conversions, it will simply make the code much more complex. You can use 
```std::enable_if and use decltype(std::declval(StringType)==std::string())```, which will fail when operator == is not present, in which case toStringView is necessary (unless of course, you want to use your own comparison algorithm).

Comment: Another thing you should notice, is that building a string view from string is an extremely cheap operation as it does not include any memory allocation / copies, and only sets a pointer and a size, so if your concern is about efficiency, it's probably not that bad.